# How to cite this community and avoid plagiarism?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask the Mathematica Stackexchange community if it is possible to use content (i.e., Mathematica codes) published by the forum users in academic papers.

If possible, I would like to hear opinions/thoughts about what is the correct manner to cite the content. The question here is: many users are identified by nicknames, and in this case it is impossible to cite the person directly. In this case should I cite the community itself, or should I try to contact the person who actuallly has presented the content/code, and ask for an authorization?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you go to any [math.se] question or answer, and click on `share > cite`, you'll see a popup containing the bibtex entry for the post. It has been used for quite some time on Math and for much longer on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net), so I guess it's safe to say that it's a respectable way to cite someone's contribution. Just copy the template from any one of their posts and change the contents accordingly.

Comment: @rm-rf I would enjoy a lot reading a paper whose bibliographic references come from a subset of (for example) "JM, rm -rf, Verbeia, belisarius, Mr. Wizard, Rojo, Jens ..." :D

Comment: @rm-rf I'm probably blind, but I see Google, Facebook, and Twitter, but not "cite."  Where is it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I thought I was the only one who didn't see this... but that's true... there is no "cite" option for us... :-(

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and Rod, http://i.stack.imgur.com/jcXpW.png

Comment: @rm-rf That's exactly the problem... the option "cite" is available for the *math.stackexchange.com* community, but unfortunately it is (somehow) **not** available for our community...

Comment: @RodLm I **explicitly** said math.se and not mathematica.se, because I know it's not available here. AFAIK, this is enabled only on math and cstheory. It's not available in other sites (including this one) because there isn't a demonstrable _need_ for it.

Comment: @rm-rf How would one go about demonstrating such a need?

Comment: @acl You could open a meta question here, tag it [tag:feature-request] and ask for the functionality. I guess they go by votes on the request (and support expressed in the comments). I don't see there being an opposition to it from SE (but you never know)

Comment: Well, it seems to be of general interest to request such a feature...

Comment: I would be interested in this feature also :)

Comment: @RodLm [Please do so](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=Can%20we%20get%20the%20BibTeX%20entry%20for%20a%20post,%20like%20Math.SE?&tags=feature-request) :)

Answer (score 6):

Referencing styles vary by journal. Here's how I once referenced a StackExchange author. In the text, I had:

The function inPolyQ from \cite{Zachar} tests whether a point is inside a polygon.

The citation was then:

István Zachar, inPolyQ, [LocatorPane and PlotRange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6031/locatorpane-and-plotrange)

The paper has yet to appear...

Comment: (Unrelated to the question) You can find alternatives (including built-ins) to test if a point is inside a polygon [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405/5)

Comment: Very cool... more "undocumented functions" that do just what you want. I'm going to have to read some of this undocumentation more carefully.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the citation, but you should be aware that I merely borrowed it from [Sjoerd](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/e_DHwhuNkWo/LwiZCHfOu8EJ) and he adopted it from Robert Sedgewick's [Algorithms](http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-4th-Robert-Sedgewick/dp/032157351X). Just a disclaimer :)

Comment: @IstvánZachar I may have incorrectly attributed it to Sedgewick. I know I had been reading his book at the time, but I also visited several web sites devoted to this problem. I may have mixed up the references and have adapted code from for instance [this page](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/), which looks very similar.

Comment: Thanks Istvan -- if my paper ever surfaces from review, I will be sure to revise the citation.